# Rails rspec controller test for adding details for Rest call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, rspec

I was just wondering if I only have to test the outcome of the controller method rather than internal set.
For example, now I have this method in the controller to add detail via a rest call to the backend and then render to the fruit detail partial page. I have to test the render_template but other than that is there anyway to test out the internal rest call response code or object ?

fruit_controller.rb

```
def add_detail
  info = {                                       <----- any way to test this
    detail: params[:detail]
    userId: session[:username]
  }
  fruitsService::Client.add_detail(params[:id], info)   <----- any way to test this 

  details = fruitsService::Client.get_detail(params[:id])  <----- any way to test this
  render(partial: fruit/detail, local:{details: details})
end
```

fruit_controller_spec.rb

```
describe '#add_comment' do
  let(details_hash) {......}

  before do
    fruitsService::Client.any_instance
    .stub(:add_detail)
    .and_return(true)

    fruitsService::Client.any_instance
    .stub(:get_comments) 
    .and_return(details_hash)

  end
  it 'successfully added a comment' do
    post :add_comment, {id: '1', info: 'foobar'}
    render(partial: 'layouts/comment_box', locals: {details: details})
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are inside a controller test, you can test the response object for a post directly. I've actually posted an answer to a similar question [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20860637/populate-the-params-hash-with-capybara-webkit/20862033#20862033), hope that's of some help.

Comment: I believe that just checking the response object. I am guessing there isn't really a way to check the if the local object is created correctly ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you would want to test the changes you have made to your `Client` directly in that case - presumably you already have one instantiated in order to test your application so you can test the instance before invoking the method and then after, checking to see if the `info` params have in fact updated the instance as you'd expect.

Comment: Alright. Ic .. so I think i should basically stub out the Client call with the correct_data if the correct data doesn't match it will error out. Thanks