# Populate the params hash with capybara webkit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, capybara-webkit

I have this route to the `user_friendships` controller's `block` action:

```
block_user_friendship PUT    /user_friendships/:id/block(.:format)     user_friendships#block
```

All you need to know is that the block action requires an `:id`.

I can test the action's resulting view in an rspec spec like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'
it "should not display the names of users who have a state of pending or requested" do
    visit "/user_friendships/1/block"
    page.should have_content("user with id of 1 blocked!")
end
```

But this is a bit of a brittle spec because the URL is hardcoded. How can I populate the `:id` entry of the params hash using the `block_user_friendship_path` variable?

This, for example, doesn't work:

```
require 'spec_helper'
it "should not display the names of users who have a state of pending or requested" do
    visit block_user_friendship_path, id: "/23"
    page.should have_content("user with id of 23 blocked!")
end
```

(Results in        `No route matches {:action=>"block", :controller=>"user_friendships"} missing required keys: [:id]` )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capybara is intended to be used for full-stack integration tests, so the recommended approach would be to avoid hardcoding URLs and instead drive Capybara to navigate through your app as a user would. This ensures that the links to the block path that are supposed to appear in your app where they're supposed to, and that they work when you click them.

Visiting the URL directly skips that, and if you need to make a `PUT` request instead of a `GET` request, it won't work correctly since `visit` is the equivalent of pasting a URL into your browser address bar: it always issues a `GET` request.

If it is working with a fully hardcoded URL, then you might want to check your routes definition. If blocking a user works on a simple `GET` request, this could be used in a [CSRF attack](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf). Destructive operations should never be triggered by `GET` requests.

Alex Lynham's answer describes a Rails/RSpec controller test, not a Capybara integration test, and if you want something lower level that does not exercise the entire stack, a controller test like the one suggested in that answer is a good way to go.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer...so you suggest passing the visit method a url string in order to emulate a browser as closely as possible?

Comment: It's often worth having two levels of testing, one at the browser/full-stack level using Capybara that simulates exactly what an end-user would do, and one at a lower level such as the controller test that Alex suggested. The lower level test is more focused and usually faster, so it's good for quick feedback and pinpointing the source of any bug that creeps in, but may miss bugs that only happen when you integrate multiple layers together.

Comment: For your full-stack integration test, the best bet is to visit the homepage of the app, then navigate using links and buttons that appear on each page.

Answer (score 13):

The reason why `visit block_user_friendship_path, id: "/23"` does not work is the syntax.

`visit block_user_friendship_path, id: "/23"`
means: pass the hash with `id: "/23"` to the **visit-method**.

What you intended to do (and thus the correct answer) is

`visit block_user_friendship_path(id: "23")`

which means: send the id of 23 to the **path-helper-method**.

Answer (score 1):

As well as the `visit` method in capybara, I know that you get the `post` method, so I assume there's also a `put` method. You can then post a specific request with params and then use the `subject` method to test the special `response` object:

```
  context "post request" do
    before do
      post 'show', format: :txt, start_at: start_at, end_at: end_at, id: user.id
    end

    subject { response }

    its(:body) do
      should include(user.name)
    end
  end
```

The above is roughly speaking production code I used to test a post request with params and then test the response body. Hopefully it should work for you (or at least point you in the right direction). Good luck!

EDIT: The `post` line obviously has some other params you don't need, I left them in illustratively in case there's anything else that you'd want to pass. Also note that this should be inside of a controller spec, not a request spec.

Answer (score 0):

You can add arguments to the helper methods and the controller can read them as usual.